# Why is a yagya/Homa called a sacrifice?

Tags: yajna

I read somewhere where the Agnihotra yagya/homa was called as a sacrifice.

Technically,a sacrifice means you give/part with, something that you have,to someone(edit:not necessarily a person,but I hope the point is clear),for a certain purpose.

[image]

When I hear the word yagya/Homa,I remember something like this.Where the pujari offers certain items in the homakund(I don’t know if this is the correct name of the brick structure enclosing the *sacrificial* fire.

What is that is being sacrificed?
Why is it sacrificed?
Is such(by such I mean a pujari offering substances to fire or chanting (Vedic) mantras,or both) a sacrifice performed in rituals like Upanayana,Marriage,Shraaddh etc?

Comment: You say - "Technically,a sacrifice means you give/part with, something that you have,to someone,for a certain purpose." Really? According to whom? You?

Comment: @Swami Vishwananda I meant sacrifice as “ give up (something valued) for the sake of other considerations.”(here “other considerations” being acquiring the pleasure of the deity worshipped).Please correct myself if I am in error.

Comment: yes. the items given into the fire are being sacrificed. in return, devatas give us natural bounties.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on the context. Sacrifice can in some circumstances mean giving something dear to us to the Divine.

> **Yajna, the fire sacrifice, is the central ritual of the Vedic
> sacrificial cult.** The basic idea of Yajna according to the Vedic
> ritualists was that man can have a happy and prosperous life only if
> he lived in harmony with his environment, consisting of Nature and the
> Devas who control the forces of Nature. Man gets his progeny and his
> sustenance as the gifts of Nature and he should express his thanks to
> the Devas. Man is required to make an offering of thanks-giving to the
> Devas a share of the good things of Nature which he gets by their
> goodwill. This offering is made through fire which is the link between
> man and the Devas. This thanks-giving takes the form of ritualistic
> fire sacrifices with offerings of commodities and utterance of Vedic
> hymns. Proper performance of these Yajnas or sacrifices secures the
> goodwill of the Devas through which man's survival and sustenance is
> assured. Later on in Chapter 4 the Gita itself speaks of other Yajnas
> (Dravya-yajna, Pranayama-yajna, Tapo-yajna, Svadhyaya-yajna and
> Jnana-Yajna) of which the fire sacrifice is only one. Thus in the Gita
> view Yajna ultimately is a symbol for all the moral and spiritual
> effort of man for his higher evolution.

**REF: adopted from the commentary of Swami Tapasyananda on Srimad Bhagavad Gita.**

It means differently in the spiritual sense.

> In the spiritual sense... sacred has a different meaning - it does not
> so much indicate giving up what is held dear as an offering of
> oneself, one's being, one's mind, heart, will, body, life, actions to
> the Divine. It has the original sense of 'making sacred' and is used
> as an equivalent of the word yajna. When the Gita speaks of the
> 'sacrifice of knowledge', it does not mean a giving up of anything,
> but a turning of the mind towards the Divine in the search for
> knowledge and as an offering of oneself through it. It is in this
> sense, too, that one speaks of the offering or sacrifice of works ...
> the European sense of the word is not the sense of the word 'Yajna'
> or the sense of 'sacrifice' in such phrases as the 'sacrifice of
> works'.  It doesn't mean that you give up all works for the sake of
> the Divine - for there would be no sacrifice of works at all.
> Similarly the  sacrifice of knowledge doesn't mean that you painfully
> and resolutely  make yourself a fool for the sake of the Lord.
> Sacrifice means an inner offering to the Divine and the real spiritual
> sacrifice is a very joyful thing. Otherwise one is only trying to make
> oneself fit and has not yet begun the real Yajna.

**Commentary by Sri Aurobindo on the Gita 3.9**

Comment: So basically “sacrifice” in this context implies **sanctification**?Would you also please mention as to in which all ceremonies are these “sacrifices” performed.

Comment: Gita 4.25 to 4.30  speaks of other Yajnas (Dravya-yajna, Pranayama-yajna, Tapo-yajna, Svadhyaya-yajna and Jnana-Yajna).  Popular fire sacrifice or yajna is only one of many possible yajnas..

Comment: Thank you for the information..!